# Proguard error on SAAgent.class

Tags: android, proguard, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

I'm developping a `Samsung Gear` application with Samsung's `accessory-v1.0.0.jar`.

When I try to create a signed apk (which preforms proguard steps) I get `Unknown verification type [10] in stack map frame` exception, because of Samsung's `SAAgent` class in `accessory-v1.0.0.jar`.

I couldn't find any solutions, do you have a workaround for this?

[Same problem (not answered on Samsung's forum) here.](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=259964)

[Similar problem on Samsung's SPen SDK (this problem was solved on a later version of SPen SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877452/proguard-4-7-with-eclipse-sdk-3-7-1-proguard-fails-with-java-io-ioexception)

**What I've tried so far, which didn't help me:**

**1)** Added below proguard elements:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.samsung.** { *; }
-keep class com.samsung.** { *; } 
-dontwarn com.samsung.**
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

**2)** Used proguard **4.7** and **4.11**.

**3)** Created a new Android project, added just accessory-v1.0.0.jar at its libs folder, I didn't write any code and tried to sign the apk. Same error occured.

```
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest] java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Devel\Workspace\SAGalleryProguardTest\libs\accessory-v1.0.0a.jar] (Can't process class [com/samsung/android/sdk/accessory/SAAgent.class] (Unknown verification type [10] in stack map frame))
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:230)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:200)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:178)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:78)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:196)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:78)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't process class [com/samsung/android/sdk/accessory/SAAgent.class] (Unknown verification type [10] in stack map frame)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:112)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:226)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   ... 6 more
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown verification type [10] in stack map frame
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.classfile.io.ProgramClassReader.createVerificationType(ProgramClassReader.java:890)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.classfile.io.ProgramClassReader.visitFullFrame(ProgramClassReader.java:659)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.classfile.attribute.preverification.FullFrame.accept(FullFrame.java:114)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.classfile.io.ProgramClassReader.visitStackMapTableAttribute(ProgramClassReader.java:452)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.classfile.attribute.preverification.StackMapTableAttribute.accept(StackMapTableAttribute.java:71)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.classfile.io.ProgramClassReader.visitCodeAttribute(ProgramClassReader.java:422)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.classfile.io.ProgramClassReader.visitProgramMethod(ProgramClassReader.java:200)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.classfile.io.ProgramClassReader.visitProgramClass(ProgramClassReader.java:142)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   at proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:91)
[2014-05-22 17:13:06 - SAGalleryProguardTest]   ... 11 more
```

Comment: I've got the same problem. I've seen a 'fix' where you can alter a proguard file, and recompile proguard, but that doesn't seem to be a solution.

I think Samsung needs to fix their jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything you can put in your ProGuard config that will fix this.  It is an issue with the `accessory-v1.0.0.jar` built by Samsung and they will have to fix it in an SDK update.

I've followed the steps set out here (http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/420/) to build a `proguard.jar` library (based on v.4.11) that will ignore this error.  Exporting a signed release apk built with ProGuard then finishes successfully.

I'm also using these config settings:

```
-keep class com.samsung.** { *; }    
-keep class * extends com.samsung.** { *; }
```

The proguard.jar I built is available here: http://www.codingcaveman.com/download/proguard.jar

You can drop it in your `AndroidSDK\tools\proguard\lib` folder, but make a copy of the original - you should probably not use it for other projects. Better yet, modify your `proguard.config` path in `project.properties` to point to a different path than the normal progaurd library.

*Disclaimer: This is a temporary workaround, not a fix - use at your own risk.  Samsung should provide a proper fix in an updated SDK.  That being said, I've not found any issues in my own testing.*

***UPDATE:*** This is no longer an issue with the Samsung Accessory SDK v2.0.19

Comment: accepted because "This is no longer an issue with the Samsung Accessory SDK v2.0.19"