# Android Proguard: Exclude jar file that already proguarded

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to apply the Proguard features in my android project, but I'm getting this error message:

> (Can't process class [com/ipay/IpayAcitivity.class] (Unknown verification type [14] in stack map frame))

I have tried searching for solutions, but no luck fixing

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877452/proguard-4-7-with-eclipse-sdk-3-7-1-proguard-fails-with-java-io-ioexception)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810219/proguard-error-on-saagent-class